# Is it possible to show multi page document in Atalasoft AtalaImageViewer?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to show tiff document in WPF application using Atalasoft`s AtalaImageViewer but the viewer shows only the first page of the document and there is no possibility (I was not able to find) to navigate to other pages.

Here is my simple XAML:

```
xmlns:atala="clr-namespace:Atalasoft.Imaging.Wpf;assembly=Atalasoft.dotImage.Wpf"

<atala:AtalaImageViewer x:Name="AtalaViewer" CanContentScroll="True"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="0 10 10 10" Source="D:\\basic-blank-residential-lease-agreement.tiff"/>
```

Does any one know how to accomplish this task?